# Dismissing a AlertDialog gives warning Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-alertdialog

I have a view with button, On click of button i am opening up a Alert Dialog. Which i am creating using below code

```
    List<String> data = new List<string> { "Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3", "Hello4" };

    void ChangeTubeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
        builder.SetTitle("Select Tube").SetItems(data.ToArray(), RowSelected);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();
        alert.Show();
    }

    void RowSelected(object senderObject, DialogClickEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.Which >= 0 && eventArgs.Which < data.Count)
        {
            String selectedHello = data.ElementAt(eventArgs.Which);
        }
    }
```

Alert shows up on UI properly and am able to select row properly. its just that when i tap outside on the screen. Alert dismisses but alse gives warning in Logcat.

```
[InputEventReceiver] Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
[ViewRootImpl[NavigationView]] Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=133.8952, y[0]=-190.78308, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=88925144, downTime=88925129, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
[InputEventReceiver] Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Should i be concerned about this warning?
And i want to keep my logs window clean. If anyone can help regarding the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not related with your code.

When you tap outside on the screen, this `ACTION_DOWN` event queued to app's Message queue. Then it is delivered to your `AlerDialog` class  through `ViewPostImeInputStage` class and finally `ViewPostImeInputStage` send this input event to `AlerDialog`'s `onTouchEvent` listener.

Since this didn't happened inside your `AlertDialog`, your `AlerDialog` will call `dismiss()` method:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    if (mCancelable && mShowing && mWindow.shouldCloseOnTouch(mContext, event)) 
    {
         cancel();//This will call dismiss() method.
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`Dissmiss()` try to close `AlertDialog` and `AlertDialog::onDetachedWindow` call `WindowInputEventReceiver::dispose()` first.

And then `ViewPostImeInputStage` call `WindowInputEventReceiver::finishInputEvent` to finish that `ACTION_DOWN` event. However `WindowInputEventReceive`r instance is already disposed so it throw warning messages.

When you create a `AlertDialog`, it will associated with a `WindowManager`, `ViewRootImpl` is bridge between `WindowManager` and a `DecorView`(its relationship with your AlertDialog like this : DecorView -> Activity -> your AlertDialog). You could this in `AlerDialog` source code  :

```
public AlertDialog create() {  
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(P.mContext, mTheme, false);  
        P.apply(dialog.mAlert);  
        dialog.setCancelable(P.mCancelable);  
        if (P.mCancelable) {  
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);  
        }  
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(P.mOnCancelListener);  
        if (P.mOnKeyListener != null) {  
            dialog.setOnKeyListener(P.mOnKeyListener);  
        }  
        return dialog;  
    }      

Dialog(Context context, int theme, boolean createContextWrapper) {  
  mContext = createContextWrapper ? new ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme) : context;  

  mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);  

  Window w = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);  
  mWindow = w;  
  w.setCallback(this);  
  w.setWindowManager(mWindowManager, null, null);  
  w.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  
  mUiThread = Thread.currentThread();  
  mListenersHandler = new ListenersHandler(this);  
}
```

The following motion event "ACTION_MOVE" can't be delievered to `AlertDialog` since it has been disposed, so the `ViewRootImpl` will `Dropping ACTION_MOVE event` and throw warning messages.

Comment: @soan saini, is there still any confusion about this question?

Comment: Sorry couldn't reply sooner. I am a new to Android development. So i expected this to be handled by platform out of box. As i am not doing anything, which is very much customised. Am just trying to show an alert with list box on UI for selection, using platform controls. So I don't know if implementing so much extra code, which i am still trying to understand. Is worth three lines in Logcat. Can i face any problem if i leave these logs as it is in App?

Comment: @soan saini, the above code I have post is source code in Android, just help you understand the workflow of `AlertDialog`, leave these logs will be OK, if you stil have problems, please feel free to cantact me.

Comment: @soan saini, still any problem?

Comment: Shen. Thanks a lot for your response. Now i see how Alert dialog is handled in Android internally. Helps me better understand the working. Will contact you in case i need any further help. Appreciate your responses.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this is the only way to get notified that dialog was dissmissed/cancelled?